# Typescript class method executing on new object instance

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, frontend, web-parts, sharepointframework

i'm comming from C# to typescript and i think maybe i'm trying to do something in the wrong way.

I have this interface:

```
export interface OilSpillInterface {
  id?: number;
  emergenceId?: number;
  weather?: string;
  insertOilSpill?: any;
}
```

I have this class:

```
export default class OilSpillPrototype implements OilSpillInterface {
  id?: number;
  emergenceId?: number;
  weather?: string;

  constructor(
    emergenceId?: number,
    weather?: string){
      this.emergenceId= emergenceId;
      this.weather= weather;
    }

  insertOilSpill= async () => {
    let _iar: ItemAddResult = await sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle("Oil Spill")
      .items.add({
        emergenceId: this.emergenceId,
        weather: this.weather
      });
    return _iar.data.ID != 0;
   }
}
```

And this is how i'm initializing the "object":

```
.
.
.
let _objOilSpill = new OilSpill(
      this.props.emergenceId,
      this.state.weather
);

console.log(_objOilSpill);
```

Even if i dont call the **insertOilSpill** method, it executes.

I think i'm trying to do this in a C# way, but i dont understand why it executes even if I dont call it.

I tried to remove the method from the interface but it executes any way.

Any tips for what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you believe `insertOilSpill` executes? The code as you've written it here can't compile (there is no type called "OilSpill" at a minimum), so it's hard to guess what the rest of the code is. Can you post code that compiles (for example in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), and demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Comment: As an example where I do not see the problem you're describing, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=37&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDyBLMBlADsssDexa0QDsoBTAJwBclUMwsBeWaAT0JFgAoBKWegPhx58sEAHtiosCQB0YUQHMOAIgBKAVQByGgJIaA4kq5CAvsFOhxUCrFHJesQiQDuCZOkzcLEqbIUdbYFxAA   What is it you're seeing that I'm not?

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for the response. I have a form component with a submit function that initializes the object. The insertOilSpill inserts the object in a sharepoint list. If i just initialize the object (without calling the insert function) i can see the item created in the list.
I used the link above to put all the code i have : shorturl.at/fyGS5 
Thanks!

Comment: And "Inserindo item na lista de oil spill" logs? And if you comment out the `new OilSpillPrototype` line, the problem goes away? I strongly suspect that the problem is elsewhere; you will debug this by simplifying this to smaller and smaller things that reproduce the problem until something doesn't reproduce, and that will show you where the problem is. Closures do not get executed just by being created; you're evaluating it somewhere. You just need to find where. (Your posted code does not actually show the problem, so I expect the precise problem is somewhere outside the code you posted.)

Comment: It logs one time but the item gets created two times.
I'm suspecting that the button click its happening two times, or something like that.
Thaks for the response again, I'm gonna try what you said, any news and i come here again.

Comment: That's even more suspicious and does not match your believed cause (which is why I suggest the cause is elsewhere). The item wouldn't get added twice if there's only one log if your belief that this closure is getting called at creation were true. Keep simplifying your example, taking out complicated things like database/network calls and replacing them with simple static functions that log, and you'll find where the real problem is.

Comment: I found the problem, my component was inside another form component, the submit event on the parent component was also triggering.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, my component was inside another form component, the submit event on the parent component was also triggering.